# How do I redirect all requests to an application running on a specific port using nginx?

Tags: redirect, nginx

I'm running an application on port 8000, and need to redirect all requests coming on port 80 to my application (port 8000). I understand that using nginx is the way to go about it. I modified ngninx.conf as follows:

```
    server {
            listen 80 default_server;
            listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index index.html index.htm;

            server_name localhost;

            location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
                    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            } 
}
```

I'm able to redirect requests to my application server now, but requests of the form xyz.com/abc return 404 not found. I thought the above would match all requests and redirect everything to the application on port 8000. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`try_files` checks the existence of a file against the defined `root` in the server block. What it's doing in the `location /` block is checking for the file, and then returning `404` when it's not found. Perhaps you wanted your config to look like this instead?:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ @my_proxy;
        }

        location @my_proxy {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        } 
}
```

Here, if `try_files` fails to find anything, it will pass over the request to you app server running on port 8000. If it still returns `404` then the file indeed doesn't exist.